# Count visits to a file/image and store to db

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, count, counter

My application is based on rails `4.2.4`. My application provides a `js` file that websites can paste into `<head></head>` and we provide some services to them.

I have seen that **Facebook** uses pixels like:

```
<noscript>
<img height='1' src='https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=63786861722982&amp;ev=PageView&amp;noscript=1' style='display:none' width='1'>
</noscript>
```

or **Amung.us**

```
<script id="_wau4dx">var _wau = _wau || []; _wau.push(["classic", "2uubkcvnbkfu", "4dx"]);
(function() {var s=document.createElement("script"); s.async=true;
s.src="//widgets.amung.us/classic.js";
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s);
})();</script>
```

To count how many visits that file has. How can I achieve the same thing with `javascript`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of serving your JS as a static asset (e.g. file served directly from disk), serve it using a normal controller action. Then add the counting bits in that controller action.

Comment: Thanks @Ariejan Im not sure what you mean. If I server it from controller action, yeah I can add the counting bits there, but If I server is as a normal controller action, how can I provide the `.js` file to user?

Comment: Thanks @Ariejan, Works perfect